# Highcharts: Can I export to the user an Excel or CSV of the raw data driving the chart?

Tags: excel, csv, highcharts, export

I have charts generated via HighCharts through a WP AdCenter plugin. I want users (admins and subscribers alike) to be able to download the raw data driving the chart as Excel or CSV, not just a PNG, JPG or PDF image of the chart. Is there a way to do this without too serious a modification of the code (I'm not a PHP programmer). Is this additional export option a feature that could be rolled out in the near future?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/cqjvD/) help you to create excel from highchart.
The **Download CSV** option added to export menu works fine. just go through that and you will do your own better.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * A small plugin for getting the CSV of a categorized chart
 */
(function (Highcharts) {

    // Options
    var itemDelimiter = ',',  // use ';' for direct import to Excel
        lineDelimiter = '\n';

    var each = Highcharts.each;
    Highcharts.Chart.prototype.getCSV = function () {
        var xAxis = this.xAxis[0],
            columns = [],
            line,
            csv = "", 
            row,
            col;

        if (xAxis.categories) {
            columns.push(xAxis.categories);
            columns[0].unshift("");
        }
        each (this.series, function (series) {
            columns.push(series.yData);
            columns[columns.length - 1].unshift(series.name);
        });

        // Transform the columns to CSV
        for (row = 0; row < columns[0].length; row++) {
            line = [];
            for (col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
                line.push(columns[col][row]);
            }
            csv += line.join(itemDelimiter) + lineDelimiter;
        }
        return csv;
    };    
}(Highcharts));

// Now we want to add "Download CSV" to the exporting menu. We post the CSV
// to a simple PHP script that returns it with a content-type header as a 
// downloadable file.
// The source code for the PHP script can be viewed at 
// https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/studies/csv-export/csv.php

Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Download CSV',
    onclick: function () {
        Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php', {
            csv: this.getCSV()
        });
    }
});



var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});

$('#getcsv').click(function () {
    alert(chart.getCSV());
});
```

Comment: FYI - the code above will keep modifying xAxis.categories every time it runs...that columns[0].unshift("") made it so that every subsequent time I would export to CSV, there'd be an additional header.  To fix this, do: columns.push( xAxis.categories.slice(0) ); to clone xAxis.categories so that you are modifying a new array.

Comment: That looks great. However, playing around with it since quite a time, I receive an error message, saying: "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems')".Any idea what this could be and how it could be solved? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: @luftikus143 are you trying to add new item to menu? could you give a fiddle of your work?

Comment: @osyan: ah, I see now. It has to do with using "exporting-old-look.src.js" (in order to have two icons for print and download). Doesn't work with that. Must use the new "general" button of Highcharts version 3; works then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it outside the scope of HighCharts. You can always pull out what the series.data values are and iterate through them to make a CSV from within javascript on the page. Or you could do it ahead of time on the backend.

Comment: Is there sample code to making the CSV in JavaScript on the page, so I don't have to rely on HighCharts (they removed their csv.php file that I had been using before it seems)

Answer (score 1):

You can add export button (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.onclick) and prepare function which will get all values from chart (kept in chart.series object) and push to string/array. Then you need to find a solution how to "produce" file in javascript, and fill it with array/string.